# Xamarin Android - fresh app created - infinite build and deploy issue (Windows 10 and MacOS Sierra)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to understand what is the problems with my project since the update to .NET Core 2.0. I am working with Xamarin since 2015 and after so long, even if the technology is so great to me, I still have so many issues with the release mod.. (build, deployment, store, etc)

Today I thought that I would some time to understand where these problems could come from. So I just created a project, this is my configuration:

## Operating System Configuration

> Edition Windows 10 Education
>   Version 1709
>   OS Build 16299.125

---

## Visual Studio

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017
>   Version 15.5.2

---

## .NET Framework

> Microsoft.NET.Framework
>   Version 4.7.02556

I just created the project and the build is infinite.... x) What did I do?

Well step by step, I did that:

- File -> New... -> Project...
- Installed -> Visual C# -> Cross-Platform -> Cross-Platform App (Xamarin.Forms)
- I then name it "NightLine"
- I don't change anything and try to build (any CPU)

Since I also have a MacBook Pro, I tried with it :) I copied the whole solution and run the `.sln` from my Mac.

## Operating System Configuration

> macOS Sierra
>   Version 10.12.6

---

## Visual Studio

> Visual Studio 2017
>   for Mac [Community]
>   Version 7.3.2

- Debug/Build -> OK
- Debug/Deploy -> Ok
- Release/Build -> Ok
- Release/Deploy -> **KO**

  ```
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Java.Interop.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Mono.Security.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains System.Core.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains System.Net.Http.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains System.Runtime.Serialization.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains System.ServiceModel.Internals.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains System.Xml.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains System.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Animated.Vector.Drawable.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Compat.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.UI.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Core.Utils.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Design.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Fragment.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Media.Compat.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Transition.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.Vector.Drawable.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v4.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.Palette.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.RecyclerView.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains Xamarin.Forms.Platform.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  EXEC : warning : Directory obj/Release/android/assets contains mscorlib.dll but no debug symbols file was found.
  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2424,2): warning : No -tsa or -tsacert is provided and this jar is not timestamped. Without a timestamp, users may not be able to validate this jar after the signer certificate's expiration date (2047-12-14) or after any future revocation date.
  /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.Debugging.targets(514,2): error : Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]
      27 Warning(s)
      1 Error(s)

  Time Elapsed 00:00:06.19
  ```

Another thing which is weird, in another console, the Application Output one, on MacOS, I have the following message, but I am not sure if it has any link:

```
    > am start -n "eip.NightLine/md5fc7575fc7d4ab373cd3cbb2310170cc6.MainActivity"
    > Starting: Intent { cmp=eip.NightLine/md5fc7575fc7d4ab373cd3cbb2310170cc6.MainActivity }
    Error type 3
    Error: Activity class {eip.NightLine/md5fc7575fc7d4ab373cd3cbb2310170cc6.MainActivity} does not exist.


     Failed to launch app: Device could not find component named: eip.NightLine/md5fc7575fc7d4ab373cd3cbb2310170cc6.MainActivity
```

Otherwise, I have everything installed, I mean in the SDK Android. I installed every elements...

Do you have any idea why it acts like that with android?

Answer (score 2):

There are two issues here and I can provide a little explanation.

### 1. `[INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]`

Represents that your `.apk` does not provide the correct ABI for your device or emulator. Thus you need to specify the specific ABI for your device/emulator:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/cpu_architectures/#How_to_Specify_Supported_Architectures

If you are unsure of which ABI to provide, you can use the following command against `adb` on a command line:

- `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist` - provides a list of compatible abis
- `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abi` - provides the best fit abi

Or simply include them all until you can run these commands and figure out what ABI you want to support in your application.

### 2. `Error type 3`

See my explanation here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=59037#c9

TLDR; This occurs when Xamarin.Android is still in an active debug session, but the application is uninstalled from the device.

You should be able to fix this issue by uninstalling your application fully from your device and clearing your `bin/obj` folders.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio:

Go to **Android Options** > **Debugging Options**. UNCKECK the **Enable Developer Instrumentation** box.

Visual Studio for Mac:

Go to **Build** > **Android Build** > **Debugging Options**. UNCKECK the **Enable Developer Instrumentation** box.

Clean and Deploy.